# Detect if browser is already loading another page

Tags: javascript

I am building some JS to install on people's websites. I am trying to detect if browser going away from page my script installed on. It would be easy to listen `beforeunload` event, but what if my script was loaded **after** user click on some link?

The events order is:

- browser loads page A with my script installed
- my script started to load
- user clicks on link to page B
- browser started to load page B
- my script is loaded to page A ← How can I detect browser location is changing right now?

Comment: How do you "install" the script? Maybe we can find a workaround for this.

Comment: The first/fast thing I can think of is to add a small `<script>` snippet listening for the `unload | beforeunload` event, before inserting your big chunk. `<script>` snippets execute as soon as the browser processes it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't detect this in this specific situation.  The act of navigating from page A will stop your script from loading, even before page B has loaded.

The relevant parts of the spec are [7.8.1 Navigating across documents](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsing-the-web.html#navigating-across-documents) which details what happens when the browser is asked to navigate (the link to page B being clicked in your example).  Step 11 says:

> Abort the active document of browsingContext.

The [abort steps](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsing-the-web.html#aborting-a-document-load) make it clear that any still-in-progress fetching or parsing of the active document are simply discarded.

Comment: [Navigator.sendBeacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) would still work, if the script was totally loaded before the link was clicked.

Comment: @Teemu OPs script hasn't loaded still at the point the link is clicked - the browser won't finish loading it.

Comment: I doubt links are clickable, before the content has been loaded ..? At least when a script is placed in the head section (without defer or async), `sendBeacon` would work.

Comment: I'm reading the Q as though the script is in another JS file as alluded to by the 2nd and 5th bullet points - links are absolutely clickable before external scripts are loaded.